# tensorflow is installed to python 2.7 instead of 3.5

Tags: python, tensorflow

I use a mac and have both Python 3.5 and 2.7 installed. I want to install tensorflow to the 3.5 version and use pip3 install tensorflow. But this installed tf only to 2.7 not to 3.5.

when I go to Finder/Applications there is only Python 2.7 and not 3.5 If I delete 2.7 completely will tf install to 3.5?

Comment: Use `pip3` to install in python3. Note: you should really look into virtual environments (either `virtualenv` package or the `venv` module)

Comment: You should really start using virtual environments. You can make a `venv` where you can define exactly which python version is used and what packages are used in it.

Comment: Always use `pythonX.Y -m pip install ...` to avoid weird version problems.

Comment: https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv

Comment: You need to use the correct wheel package with pip3 install https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-1.3.0-py3-none-any.whl or a wheel for the GPU. There are some packages built by the community like https://github.com/bodak/tensorflow-wheels/releases.